# Aggregation + Multiplicity UML Clarification

Tags: java, uml, aggregation, bidirectional-relation, multiplicity

[image: UML : Aggregation + Multiplicity]

I don't understand what the hollow diamond next to Class A together with the multiplicity next to Class B implies about the relationship between Class A and B. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: May be you could read some UML documentation?

Answer (score 2):

- Aggregation is a special type of Association.
- The lives of both objects are independent of each other.
- Both objects have their own life cycle.
- Define the aggregation name.
- The direction of the empty diamond specifies which object contains
  the other object.

For an example,

[image]

For your question,

> I don't understand what the hollow diamond next to Class A together
>   with the multiplicity next to Class B implies about the relationship
>   between Class A and B. Could someone clarify this for me?

What the multiplicity does is  every Class A  objects associated with zero to many Class B objects and also the **Class B depends on Class A but they both have their own life cycles** like the example that i gave unlike `Composition`.

EDIT:

Like this ,

[image]

You have to specify in both sides whether how many objects involved with Class B objects.Like in 0..n in Class B side.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Class A is an aggregate class made up of zero to many constituent Class B objects?

Comment: @WalterPark Yes, that's correct.I hope it make sense.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my earlier comment. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: @WalterPark yes, but you have to note that in Class A to show that 1 or n number of objects connected with 0 or n number of objects of Class B

Comment: @WalterPark If you figured that out, mark my answer as the accepted one

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say in "you have to note that in Class A to show that 1 or n number of objects connected with 0 or n number of objects of Class B." Could you please clarify.

Comment: @WalterPark I edited the answer.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: So in Class A you would have a field like **private Collection<ClassB>** which would latter be initialized in it's constructor as a List or Set. Whereas in Class B you would have no field relating to Class A.

Comment: @WalterPark: that is correct. A collection is one valid way to implement that multiplicity. However, note that in UML, the multiplicity is written as [0..*], or just [*]. It is never written with letters.